# Leaflet Canvas Libraries

Tags: javascript, canvas, leaflet, leaflet.draw

There are a number of libraries that provide drawing on a canvas such as:

[Leaflet.Canvas-Markers](https://github.com/eJuke/Leaflet.Canvas-Markers)

[leaflet-canvas-layer](https://github.com/CartoDB/Leaflet.CanvasLayer)

[Leaflet.Canvas-Flowmap-Layer](https://github.com/jwasilgeo/Leaflet.Canvas-Flowmap-Layer)

[gLayers.Leaflet](https://github.com/Sumbera/gLayers.Leaflet)

[react-leaflet-canvas-layer](https://github.com/Esorakouki/react-leaflet-canvas-layer)

However, I know leaflet canvas rendering has come along way and wondering if these libraries are somewhat redundant now.

Does Leaflet internal canvas rendered basically has the same functionally of these other library's?

Or in other words can everything done in these other library's be done within leaflet canvas renderer?

Comment: Those are all the *exact same library*.

Comment: @Jack Bashford Did you look at the links? They are not the same. I'm asking if those library's functionally is now present within leaflet itself now with the canvas renderer. Or do they do something differently

Comment: Open all the links - they all go to the *exact same library* - https://github.com/Esorakouki/react-leaflet-canvas-layer. You only have one link in your question.

Comment: @Jack Bashford, your right my bad. I must have loss the other links when formatting. Will fix shortly

Comment: @Jack Bashford, okay fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Leaflet internal canvas rendered basically has the same functionally of these other library's?

No.

Leaflet's `L.Canvas` provides support for rendering lines, polygons and circles. The plugins you listed provide support for drawing other stuff (e.g. bezier curves, arcs, per-tile canvases).